# Destruct twice after reset on shared pointer

Tags: shared-ptr, destructor, swap, reset

Here the source code :

```
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(_activeFQDNMutex);
    activeFQDNs.swap(shadowFQDNs);
    shadowFQDNs.reset(new TrieRegexInterface());
```

After reset, there is a core file, which shows the object pointed by shadowFQDNs was destructed twice.

Anyone has idea ?

I am doubting after swap call, the object pointed by activeFQDNs can be referenced by another shared pointer since shadowFQDNs has not been locked.